# Multiple value queries to find nearest matching row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to create a query that returns the nearest matching row for a set of values. The values are typically between 1-3 (one is 1-5).

I'm not sure the best way to approach right this script. I've had some people say that using distance is the way, and I've had others say that using where/or is the way. Basically the result doesn't have to be an exact match, it just has to list the results in rank of closeness.

The form on [this page](http://clickfitgolf.com/drivers.aspx) here is basically what I'm trying to replicate. If anyone could shed light on the approach to the query that I should take that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: nearest text match? nearest integer match? if integer, then you would simply add a calculated column that contains the distance from the value and sort on distance. Not sure how a where/or match would work,

Comment: Integer, but multiple integers

Comment: multiple integers, in the same column?

Comment: multiple columns, multiple rows. the website in the question hopefully should give an idea of what i'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: Unfortunately i can't follow it.

Comment: basically matching up multiple values against rows in a database. values are in multiple columns but queried against all rows

Comment: I would still take the distance approach, use a calculated column for each match you want to test, then sort by each of the calculated columns in order of dominance. Or, even a single calculated column totaling the distance of them all.

Comment: Step 1 has sto be 'define nearest match'! And keep it really simple to begin with.

Comment: Nice, if either of you could post your ideas as an answer that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a calculated overall "distance" by getting sum the absolute value of the selected number minus the column value for all columns.

```
SELECT id, ABS(5-col1)+ABS(5-col2)+ABS(5-col3) as distance
FROM sometable
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

where `5` is the value you are comparing against.